# Wrong header included by compiler

Tags: ros, include, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've asked a [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/49962/get-forward-kinematics-tutorial-failed/?comment=50190#comment-50190) about execution error of a kinematics tutorial. After much discussion with dornhege, we guessed that the problem might be the hearder file being included was wrong.

When I wrote a program which included "kinematics_msgs/GetKinematicSolverInfo.h", it would not link the one in [/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/arm_navigation/kinematics_msgs], instead it would link the header in [/opt/ros/fuerte/include/kinematics_msgs].

However, the definition of the header in the latter path is out dated, the correct one is from the former, which is a package you can roscd into. This caused the following problem when I ran the program :

```
[ERROR] [1354979145.382429702, 11715.590000000]: client wants service /pr2_right_arm_kinematics/get_fk to have md5sum 47de11a2bc125445e74531db0e2d1c21, but it has 2088007c8963e2252a67c872affa0985. Dropping connection.
```

I've tried another two computers and got the same problem, but this didn't happen on dornhege's computer. How to solve this problem? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50241/wrong-header-included-by-compiler/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like you have installed the packages ros-fuerte-arm-navigation and ros-fuerte-moveit-msgs on your computer. The former provides the version in /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/arm_navigation while the latter provides /opt/ros/fuerte/include/kinematics_msgs.

I would consider this as a bug in the ROS packages and to solve it, I guess you will have to remove one of the two packages from your system. Also, consider filing it at the moveit bug tracker.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-12-12**:
I've removed the ros-fuerte-moveit-msgs package and everything got fine ! Thanks. I would like to ask one more question. Instead of removing ros-fuerte-moveit-msgs, can I tell my package to include the correct header from /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/arm_navigation/kinematics_msgs?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-12**:
I think it's a bug in the dependencies of the arm_kinematics package and should be fixed there. I think filing a ticket is the right thing to do here.